# Flutter: applying removeAt to a List with the nested objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List that contains nested objects.

```
List _haha = [
     {id: 'aaa'},
     {id: 'bbb'},
     {id: 'ccc'},
     {id: 'ddd'},
];
```

I want to delete `'aaa'` inside the `_haha`. Currently, I did

```
int _indexVal = _haha.indexWhere((e) => e['id'] == 'aaa');
```

And, use this int value to remove the item inside the list. Is there any way that I can use `.removeAt` with one single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oneliner with `.removeAt()`:

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, String>> haha = [
    {'id': 'aaa'},
    {'id': 'bbb'},
    {'id': 'ccc'},
    {'id': 'ddd'},
  ];

  haha.removeAt(haha.indexWhere((item) => item['id'] == 'aaa'));
}
```

But, you may be more interested in using the `.removeWhere()` method.

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, String>> haha = [
    {'id': 'aaa'},
    {'id': 'bbb'},
    {'id': 'ccc'},
    {'id': 'ddd'},
  ];

  haha.removeWhere((item) => item['id'] == 'aaa');
}
```